# accessing a form control from a module [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net, forms

Can I reach/access a form control object from a module in VB.NET ? I have a webbrowser in the Form , so my question is can i access it from a module (changing settings for example). I have no idea how to do this .

Comment: Please provide more info.

Comment: My question is : I have a webbrowser control over a form , how can i access the settings of this webbrowser from a module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control has to come in as a parameter. Since the Module behaves as a static (shared) class, it has no state or access to instance members natively.

```
Module MyModule

    Public Shared Sub MyMethod(ByVal myControl as WebUserControl)

        ' do your mojo

    End Sub

End Module
```

If you just want to have global access from the page level you can send the Page in, but you'll need to perform a recursive search for various controls and you won't have access to the rendered output, so databound controls such as GridViews or FormViews will not work the same way and will be subject to the event lifecycle.

```
Public Shared Sub MyMethod(ByVal myPage as Page)

End Sub
```